# Sugar daddy scam?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I’ve entered into a sugar daddy arrangement, but this is entirely new to me. I’ve read many things about scams and not to give out my bank account login. Well I was stupid and gave it out but as of now and without my sugar daddy knowing I completely changed the login and security questions. I’ve contacted my bank as well. The only thing is I’m not sure if it’s a scam or not. He paid my phone bill completely and appears serious about our arrangement. I haven’t sent him anything at all and he’s been very kind of me.

Comment: ...if you have to ask, then it's probably a scam.

Comment: When you say he paid your phone bill completely, you mean that he used his own money, not that he entered the payment order into your online banking, right?

Comment: *He paid my phone bill completely* depending on the method he used to pay your phone bill, you may be surprised at some point in the immediate future to find that the transaction was fraudulent (and done as a front to gain your confidence).

Comment: Maybe I'm just getting old, but the whole concept of a "sugar daddy" arrangement seems scammy to me.  I mean, even if he's not out to break into your bank account or launder money through you, surely he still *wants something* right?  Pictures?  Dirty texts maybe? That sort of thing?  I mean, I'm a dude (and, per above, getting older) so I'm not really a prime target for this sort of thing myself, but nobody gives away money for literally nothing in exchange.  Even if there's no threat right now, establishing a relationship where you're indebted like this may lead to one later on.

Comment: @Steve-O My understanding is these sugar daddy scams do have a veneer of "you have to send me flirty texts / photos" to make them seem legit.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah that's what I figured, but my point is even *that* doesn't really strike me as "legit."  Even if it's exactly what it seems, it's still a dangerous proposition that could easily turn sour once you've grown to depend on this person's "free" money.

Comment: @Steve-O Oh, very much so. People have been killed in the meatspace versions of these arrangements, and stalking's a major issue for many participating.

Answer (score 0):

It's been said before, not only in this sort of case but with anything in life : If it looks too good to be true, it probably is.

If you get the sligthest doubt, if it causes you anxiety or stress, back off. Getting paid a few things by someone is all fun and games until it causes more negative than it does positive.

If he's serious about it, well talk about it with him. If he's willing to take another route to satisfy your "needs", like I don't know, send you interac payments by email for example, which is safer than giving him access to your account, well you will already be much safer.

But golden rules with anything = Don't give him access to your accounts, and do not give him information which could potentially give him this access : It's not worth the risk.